# how to create dynamic function in javascript with for loop and its index inside function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
    var data = ["s","a"]
    var asyncFunctionss = [];

    for (var i in data) {
        asyncFunctionss.push(function (callback) {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }
    for (var g in asyncFunctionss) {
        asyncFunctionss[g]();
    }
```

I try to run this program it give the following output.

Expected Output

0

1

Actual Output

1

1

How to achieve the Expected output ?

Comment: @melpomene wow, forEach method works for me. thank you so much.

Comment: forEach has it's own scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript). The reason is that as soon as a function element in *asyncFunctionss* is called the variable *i* is already 1. You could use a IIFE to remember the value of variable *i*:

```
var data = ["s","a"]
var asyncFunctionss = [];

for (var i in data) {
  (function(i){
    asyncFunctionss.push(function (callback) {
        console.log(i);
    });
  })(i);
}
for (var g in asyncFunctionss) {
    asyncFunctionss[g]();
}
```